# count no. of pairs such that absolute difference is less than K

Tags: algorithm, counting

Given an array A of size N, how do I count the number of pairs(`A[i]`, `A[j]`) such that the absolute difference between them is less than or equal to K where K is any positive natural number? (`i`, `j<=N` and `i!=j`)

My approach:

1. Sort the array.
2. Create another array that stores the absolute difference between two consecutive numbers.

Am I heading in the right direction? If yes, then how do I proceed further?

Comment: What is the size of array A? If it is not too big, you can just do `for (i=0;i<size;i++) for (j=i+1; j<size;j++) if (abs(A[i]-A[j])<=K) res++;`

Comment: The size of the array is close to 10^6.I earlier tried with naive algorithm but it takes long time.I need an efficient algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a **O(nlogn)** algorithm :-

```
1. sort input
2. traverse the sorted array in ascending order.
3. for A[i] find largest index A[j]<=A[i]+k using binary search.
4. count = count+j-i
5. do 3 to 4 all i's
```

**Time complexity :-**

```
Sorting : O(n)
Binary Search : O(logn)
Overall : O(nlogn)
```

Comment: sorting will take nlogn

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is partially correct. You first sort the array. Then keep two pointers i and j.

```
1. Initialize i = 0, j = 1.  
2. Check if A[j] - A[i] <= K.   
   - If yes, then increment j,  
   - else
       - **increase the count of pairs by C(j-i,2)**. 
       - increment i.
       - if i == j, then increment j.  
3. Do this till pointer j goes past the end of the array. Then just add C(j-1,2) to the count and stop.
```

By i and j, you are basically maintaining a window within which the difference between elements is <= K.

EDIT: This is the basic idea, you will have to check for boundary conditions. Also you will have to keep track of the past interval that was added to the count. You will need to subtract the overlap with the current interval to avoid double counting.

**Complexity: O(NlogN), for the sort operation, linear for the array traversal**

Comment: Downvoter, please tell me what is wrong. Will correct it if need be.

Comment: I think it's clearer to express this as: for each i, move j up to the point where A[j] - A[i] > K (or j=N), then add j-i-1 to the counts.

Comment: @typedef Yes, C means combination.

Comment: @Anonymous, no, we need to increment by all possible pairs between i and j.

Comment: I don't believe this returns the correct result, and it's also not clear what to do when j drops off the end of the array. Test case: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], K=10.

Comment: @Anonymous If j goes beyond the end of array, it simply means that all pairs of all elements beyond i have a difference less than K. So just calculate C(j-i,2) and stop. EDITED to make it clear.

Comment: @Anonymous, in your case, the count will just be C(6,2) = 15.

Comment: And how about: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1000], K=10?

Comment: @Anonymous in this case j will stop at the last element. And yes before counting you will have to subtract the overlap with the past interval counted to avoid double counting.

Answer (score 1):

This is O(n^2):

```
Sort the array  
For each item_i in array,
  For each item_j in array such that j > i
      If item_j - item_i <= k, print (item_j, item_i)
      Else proceed with the next item_i
```

Comment: Thanks,But I want the complexity of algorithm to be O(nlogn) or O(n).

Comment: @typedef, I thought we need to print the pairs, in which case I don't think you can do O(nlgn).

Answer (score 0):

Once your array is sorted, you can compute the sum in O(N) time.

Here's some code. The O(N) algorithm is pair_sums, and pair_sums_slow is the obviously correct, but O(N^2) algorithm. I run through some test cases at the end to make sure that the two algorithms returns the same results.

```
def pair_sums(A, k):
    A.sort()
    counts = 0
    j = 0
    for i in xrange(len(A)):
        while j < len(A) and A[j] - A[i] <= k:
            j+=1
        counts += j - i - 1
    return counts

def pair_sums_slow(A, k):
    counts = 0
    for i in xrange(len(A)):
        for j in xrange(i+1, len(A)):
            if A[j] - A[i] <= k:
                counts+=1
    return counts

cases = [
    ([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 10),
    ([0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 1),
    ([0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16], 9),
    ([0, -1, -2, 1, 2], 2)
]

for A, k in cases:
    want = pair_sums_slow(A, k)
    got = pair_sums(A, k)
    if want != got:
        print A, k, want, got
```

The idea behind `pair_sums` is that for each i, we find the smallest j such that A[j] - A[i] > K (or j=N). Then j-i-1 is the number of pairs with i as the first value.

Because the array is sorted, j only ever increases as i increases, so the overall complexity is linear since although there's nested loops the inner operation `j+=1` can occur at most N times.